# OpenGL: How can I change my coordinate setup?

Tags: opengl

From what I understand, OpenGL uses a right-hand coordinate system, that, at least in clip space, works like this:

- X points right
- Y points up
- Z points into the screen

This means that, without any modifications to all the matrices used for transformations, world space coordinates work like this:

- The X-Z plane is horizontal
- The X-Y and Z-Y planes are vertical

What if I want to change it so that the Z axis is the one pointing up? How could I go about doing this? I've thought about multiplying all matrices by a rotation matrix that just shifts all coordinates by 90 degrees, or maybe I could change the Y and Z components of a vector once I send data to the GPU, but those seem more like workarounds than actual solutions, and they might also take a hit on performance if done for *every* mesh in the scene. Is there any standard way to do this? Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: You can multiply a Rotationmatrix onto it.

Comment: Have you tried http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28434/multiply-matrix-by-vector-what-to-do-if-need-to-change-y-up-to-z-up? Also to be pedantic, +Z points out of the screen in a right-handed system. Though OpenGL is left-handed in NDC-space (which matches your bullet points).

Comment: @ssell thank you for the link, that's pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clip and NDC spaces are left-handed axis system, not as you defined each X,Y,Z, axis.

You can have several axis systems. For example some "objects store" use a left-handed system. If you're starting with OpenGL, try to set everything in right-handed system, will be easier for you to understand.

Your objects are normally defined in its own local system (right handed or not). You place them by a "world" matrix. And you see the world from a camera position, which requieres a "view" matrix. And then you project all of them, another "proj" matrix.

As you can see, **matrices are used everywhere**. Don't be afraid of them.

Changing from an axis system to another is just another matrix. There are many examples in the web.